# How to handle Mediadevices FriendlyName when null

Tags: c#, mediadevices

I was working with MediaDevice library , it went okay when the device name match the FriendlyName,
My problem is when i dont plug in my device into the PC or i change a simple letter in FriendlyName

```
var devicess = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
using (var device = devicess.First(d => d.FriendlyName == "MyCellPhone"))
{
    device.Connect();

    // get list of available storages (SD-Card, Internal Flash, ...)
    var objects = device.FunctionalObjects(FunctionalCategory.Storage);
    MediaStorageInfo infoss = GetStorageInfo(objects.First());
    ulong size = infoss.FreeSpaceInBytes;

    device.Disconnect();
}
```

for Example if my smartphone is named "samsung" an i put "samsam" in here

```
 using (var device = devicess.First(d => d.FriendlyName == "samsam")) (instead of samsung)
```

the app crashes , the same thing if leave it empty or i run the code with no phone attached.
i tried some try {} catch{} but no result.
Can any one help me please .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`:

```
var device = devicess.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FriendlyName == "MyCellPhone")
```

This will return null if it can't find a match, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: this worked like magic ,i really did not think this would be the solution.. thank you very much.